# I want to update some html inside google doc for some placeholders

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

```
function insertDataToDoc(copiedDocId, placeholder, contentToReplace) {
  placeholder = '{{Response'+ placeholder+'}}';
  //placeholder = '{{Response1}}';
  Logger.log(placeholder);
  
    // Open the copied Google Doc
    var copiedDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copiedDocId);

    // Access the body of the Google Doc
    var body = copiedDoc.getBody();
    
    // Get the full text of the body
    var content = body.getText();

    // Find the position of the placeholder in the text
    var placeholderIndex = content.indexOf(placeholder);

    if (placeholderIndex !== -1) {
        // Extract the text before and after the placeholder
        var textBefore = content.substring(0, placeholderIndex);
        var textAfter = content.substring(placeholderIndex + placeholder.length);

        // Clear the existing content of the body
        body.clear();

        // Set the text before the placeholder
        if (textBefore.trim() !== '') {
            body.appendParagraph(textBefore);
        }

        // Insert the new content
        beautifyContent(contentToReplace,body);
        

        // Set the text after the placeholder
        if (textAfter.trim() !== '') {
            body.appendParagraph(textAfter);
        }
    }

    // Save the changes
    copiedDoc.saveAndClose();
}



  function beautifyContent(content, body) {

    // content =     "1. This is the first item in a list.\n" +
    // "2. This is the second item.\n" +
    // "This is a regular paragraph, not a list item.\n" +
    // ". This is also considered a list item.";

    // Split the content into paragraphs
    Logger.log('we r in beautify code');
    let paragraphs = content.split('\n');

    // Iterate through each paragraph    
    for (let paragraph of paragraphs) {
        // Check if a paragraph starts with a number followed by a dot, or just a dot
        if (paragraph.match(/^\d+\./) || paragraph.startsWith('.')) {
            // Remove the numbering like "1.", "2.", ..., or a standalone dot
            let cleanedParagraph = paragraph.replace(/^\d*\.\s*/, '');
            Logger.log('This is a list item');
            let listItem = body.appendListItem(cleanedParagraph);  
            listItem.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.NUMBER);           
            //listItem.setForegroundColor('#FFFF00'); // Yellow color
        }
        else if (paragraph.trim() !== '') {
            Logger.log('This is a paragraph');
            let para = body.appendParagraph(paragraph);            
            //para.setForegroundColor('#FF0000'); // Red color
        }
    }
}
```

I have written above 2 method which append some paragraph or list item in between my google doc as i dint get any method like body.appendhtml or inserthtml so i had to follow long way. but what it does, it considers all content above placeholder as a paragraph and all formatting of google doc goes off. Please guide me better way to update the placeholder inside google doc without disturbing the rest formatting

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Why do you wish to insert html into a google document?  It's not really an html document.  It runs on a server not on your browser.